# How to mark current line and move cursor to next line?

Tags: mark

How do I mark the current line and then move the cursor to the beginning of the next line?  I'd like it to behave like Sublime Text's <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd>.

Comment: In addition to kaushal's answer, you may find the commands `M-h` (`mark-paragraph`) and `C-M-h` (`mark-defun`) useful, as they may eliminate the need for such a command much of the time.

Comment: Would you mind to describe the behaviour of Sublime more precise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below works with brief testing:

- If no region is selected to begin with, the current line will be selected and the cursor will move to the next line (default, if no prefix arg is used).
- If a region is already selected, all this command will do is move the cursor to the next line (default, if no prefix arg is used).

With that functionality, hitting `C-l` once will select only the current line. But hitting `C-l` consecutive times will keep on adding consecutive lines to the selection.

```el
(defun my/select-current-line-and-forward-line (arg)
  "Select the current line and move the cursor by ARG lines IF
no region is selected.

If a region is already selected when calling this command, only move
the cursor by ARG lines."
  (interactive "p")
  (when (not (use-region-p))
    (forward-line 0)
    (set-mark-command nil))
  (forward-line arg))
;; Note that I would not recommend binding this command to `C-l'.
;; From my personal experience, the default binding to `C-l' to
;; `recenter-top-bottom' is very useful.
(global-set-key (kbd "C-l") #'my/select-current-line-and-forward-line)
```

---

I'd like to add that I personally prefer simply doing `C-a C-SPC` followed by `C-n` or `C-p` or `M-{` or `M-}`.

- `C-a C-SPC` will take the cursor to the beginning of the line and set the mark.
- After that the selection will expand based on the navigation command you use.

Using this generic approach will give you much more flexibility on how you change your selection.

Comment: A useful change may be adding an arg `arg`, using `(interactive "p")`, and changing `(forward-line 1)` to `(forward-line arg)`.

Comment: @nanny Good point

Comment: Does changing `use-region-p` by `region-active-p` make difference  in the function `my/select-current-line-and-forward-line`?

Comment: @Name It should work fine even if you use `region-active-p` here.

Comment: If I don't give `arg` a value as prefix arg and `RET` directly, your function will still move down 1 line, does it mean that `1` is the default argument?

Answer (score 1):

**Shift Selection Mode**

If the cursor is at the beginning of a line: <kbd>C-S-n</kbd> or in another notation <kbd>C-N</kbd>. 
If not, please type: <kbd>C-a C-S-n</kbd> (which is in my notation <kbd>C-aN</kbd>, since you have to type the `<CTRL>` key just once). By the way `shift-selection-mode`is `t` by default.

Comment: This is in most cases a better answer as it does not need any additional configs.

Answer (score 0):

Could you mean a combination of `C-e` and `C-j`? If yes, you can remap it via a keyboard macro :

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-return>") (kbd "C-e C-j"))
```